# App crashes when zoomed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

my app has a grid which contains 15 images.
I have used the code for zooming from this link:http://blog.chevonchristie.com/getting-the-windows-phone-blog-rolling-with-image-zooming/#comment-1058

Setting the zoom to every image in the grid.the zoom works very nice but the problem is when i zoom the images and try to change the images on some button the app crashes and the debug window shows me insufficient memory problem,why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a memory leak problem. Did you make sure to call WP7ImageZoomer.EndImageZooming(myImage); on each image before changing them and when you navigate away from the page?
 Otherwise memory leak could come from event that you are regitering on object which are long lived and that you never unregister.

Comment: I have solved the problem of crashing by setting the zoom to grid and not the image but the images appear blur.how can i solve this problem